# Errors using reledmac in Hebrew

Tags: xetex, hebrew, reledmac

I am trying to use reledmac (v2.31.0) with xelatex to typeset a Hebrew text with Hebrew commentary.
The document fails on the fourth compile with

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.6 ]
```

Here is a minimal example.  If I shorten the text by reducing to only one `\lorem` after each `\edtext` it succeeds without error.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{b5paper}
\usepackage[parapparatus,series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O}

\renewcommand{\footfudgefiddle}{71}
\Xarrangement[A]{normal}
\Xlemmaseparator{.}
\Xnonumber[A]
\Xnotefontsize[A]{\small}
\Xwraplemma[A]{\textbf}

\makeatletter
\def\right@footnoterule{}
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\begin{center}\large\textbf{פירוש}\end{center}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\lorem}{אל מלא ויקי מדעי, את החלה תורת עיצוב עוד. שמו קבלו
ספרות את, גם אנא אחרים באגים, לוח אודות אספרנטו אם. כתב את לעברית לויקיפדיה
ביוטכנולוגיה, ברוכים חבריכם שער את. גם כניסה ערכים שמו, בה שמו שאלות
וכמקובל, ב קרן לכאן לשון מיזם. בה זכר הספרות היסטוריה האנציקלופדיה. צ'ט גם
הרוח פילוסופיה.}

\begin{document}
\author{אריה לייב טוראג}
\title{\texthebrew{הספר שלי}}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{שער ראשון}

\begin{hebrew}
\numberlinefalse
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\edtext{הקטע הראשון}{\Afootnote{\lorem \par \lorem}}
\lorem
\lorem
\edtext{הקטע השני}{\Afootnote{\lorem}}
\lorem
\lorem
\edtext{הקטע השלישי}{\Afootnote{\lorem}}
\lorem
\lorem
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306975/8746), which might be relevant, but I am not sure how to apply that to my document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bug with `numberlinefalse` and something with hebrew. This feature was a wrong good idea, because it has many board effect. I have decided to stop maintening it.

As explained in the handbook, you should not use it with critical footnotes (`\Afootnote` and related). So

- delete `\numberlinefalse`
- set `\firstlinenum` to a big value.

So

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{b5paper}
\usepackage[parapparatus,series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O}
\firstlinenum{10000000}
\renewcommand{\footfudgefiddle}{71}
\Xarrangement[A]{normal}
\Xlemmaseparator{.}
\Xnonumber[A]
\Xnotefontsize[A]{\small}
\Xwraplemma[A]{\textbf}

\makeatletter
\def\right@footnoterule{}
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\begin{center}\large\textbf{פירוש}\end{center}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\lorem}{אל מלא ויקי מדעי, את החלה תורת עיצוב עוד. שמו קבלו
ספרות את, גם אנא אחרים באגים, לוח אודות אספרנטו אם. כתב את לעברית לויקיפדיה
ביוטכנולוגיה, ברוכים חבריכם שער את. גם כניסה ערכים שמו, בה שמו שאלות
וכמקובל, ב קרן לכאן לשון מיזם. בה זכר הספרות היסטוריה האנציקלופדיה. צ'ט גם
הרוח פילוסופיה.}

\begin{document}
\author{אריה לייב טוראג}
\title{\texthebrew{הספר שלי}}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{שער ראשון}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
\edtext{הקטע הראשון}{\Afootnote{\lorem \par \lorem}}
\lorem
\lorem
\edtext{הקטע השני}{\Afootnote{\lorem}}
\lorem
\lorem
\edtext{הקטע השלישי}{\Afootnote{\lorem}}
\lorem
\lorem
\pend

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Note that you must delete the `.1` file.

Comment: Fantastic!!  Thank you so much @Maïeul!